# SAPI 5.4 audio output parameters

Tags: windows, delphi, text-to-speech, sapi

I have the following, very simple code (delphi/Object Pascal) which uses Microsoft SAPI 5.4 to do some Text To Speech

```
// init
var engine : tspvoice;
var voice  : ispeechobjecttoken;
engine:=tspvoice.Create(nil);

// pick the first voice and assign it to the engine
voice := ISpeechObjectToken(0);
engine.Voice := Voice;

// speak
engine.Speak(text, SVSFlagsAsync);
```

However I don't see any control on the output format (Bits per sample / Frequency). I have a sample app (TTSapp) coming from an old SAPI SDKdownload, which allows to control such parameters. Unfortunately I can't locate its source code anywhere, and I can't find any download to an up-to-date sapi SDK too.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I typically don't use delphi, but I do have an example in C++ if it helps. In this case you can see I'm messing with the CSpStreamFormat and then calling SPBindToFile to set it. sapi.h has all the SPSTREAMFORMAT types you can use.

```
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpVoiceToken;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;

    CSpStreamFormat cAudioFmt;
    CComPtr<ISpStream> cpStream;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = cAudioFmt.AssignFormat(SPSF_22kHz16BitMono);
    hr = SPBindToFile(L"E:\\fileName.wav", SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS, &cpStream, &cAudioFmt.FormatId(), cAudioFmt.WaveFormatExPtr());
    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
    cpVoice->SetOutput(cpStream, TRUE);
    hr = cpVoice->Speak(L"My spoken text goes here", SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);

    cpStream->Close();
    cpStream.Release();
    cpVoice.Release();

    ::CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I was aware of this, I already use the above when recording TTS to a Wav file. My problem is that I don't see the same level of control (Audio Format parameters) for real time output. Yet, some SAPI test apps allow the user to adjust the audio output format for wave out.